# How do I block a part of an url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

So basically, I have a link looking like:

```
mydomain.com/file.php?id=m03u7dp255jiobi&type=mp3
```

How do I block access to this URL only for this `?id=` part

So when users visit this link `file.php?id=test` it won’t work, but if they visit the other link looking like this `?id=validurl` it will work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to block access to the webpage if the value of `id` is invalid?

Comment: yeah, I want to block access to this url - ?id=m03u7dp255jiobi&type=mp3

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean... What is an example of a valid URL? What are the rules to define something as invalid?

Comment: so I have a file hosting service, and all the links are looking like this - ?id=randomsymbols&type=mp3, i want to block some of these urls in the htaccess, so if someone tries to access id=random_url_i_want_to_block&type=mp3 it will show the 403 error

Comment: Okay, how many do you want to block? If it's a few you could do it in `.htaccess` if there's a lot you'd do better to pass it off to a controller (I believe this question was tagged with `PHP` previously?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### .htaccess

To do this in `.htaccess` you can use the `mod_rewrite` module and set conditions against the query string.

```
ReWriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=invalid_string [OR]
ReWriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=another_invalid_string
ReWriteRule . /new_destination.php [QSD,L,R=307]
```

- `OR` - Literally an `OR` operator; as in `Condition1 || Condition 2`
- `QSD` - Removes the original query string
- `L` - Stops further rewrite rules from being applied
- `R=307` - Sets a `307 Temporary Redirect` status code

  - `R=401` Sets an *Unauthorised* status code and redirects automatically to a predefined `401` resource (`ErrorDocument`)

    - You can custom set the `ErrorDocuments` like:

      ```
      ErrorDocument 401 /errors/unauthorised.php
      ```